# Program Arguments in Java input

Tags: java

I have a combo arguments to run a Java App with main method. Arguments like

```
-O filename=Name -a MainApp -c projectName.properties -id SomeProcessor -e projectName-dev.properties
```

What is the meaning of `-c`, `-e`, `-id`, `-a`, `-O`? Are they with default meanings, or we should set them?

If we can set them, where to check what's the meaning? And how can we set them?

Comment: I suppose these options is set somewhere in program, but I have no idea how to set them and how to check

Answer (score 0):

They mean whatever the programmer of the `main` method decided they should mean.

Usually, a command-line program like that will list the options if you run it with no options, or a `-?` or `--help` option.

Comment: It run with options, what is relation between option and arguments

Comment: Options are either 1) flag arguments, where presence mean "flag on", e.g. `-v` meaning verbose mode, or 2) named arguments, where option is followed by argument value, e.g. `-d MyDir` or `--dir=MyDir`. They are a way to structure the arguments. Google "[Options vs. Arguments](https://www.google.com/search?q=Options+vs.+Arguments&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" for more info.

Comment: These are not standard options, do you know how and where to set them

Comment: How and where to set *what*? The options you listed in question are non-standard and defined by whoever wrote the program, as I already said in this answer. The options I mentioned are *examples*, so not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

From a shell, type `java --help` and you will see all of the arguments provided by the JDK's binary. All of these other arguments are custom used by program you're running. Each is represented as one of the values in the `args` variable in the *main* method of the class or Jar file being executed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```

Comment: This is obviously customized argument options, they are not standard java options which we can check with java - help command

Comment: ...which is precisely what my second sentence expressed.